# Performance in Apache POI in time write file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a problem with performance write file in POI. I'am writing about 400 rows(100 iterations), and work time about 2 minutes. It's very long. I using style, merge rows, autosize. If about 800 iterations then work time 3 hours.

first iteration - 60-70ms next increased +10-20ms. On 35 iteration work time 1sec.

But I commented setStyle then time 5-10sec. Could you please help me? May be use SXFFWorkbook?

my code:

```
try (BufferedInputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileCalc))) {

            ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(-1.0d);
            xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = xssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);

            // Строка старта шапки
            int rowStartHead = 0;
            int numberTable = 1;
            for (TotalModel totalModel: listTotalModel) {
                if (totalModel != null) {

                    // Строка финиша шапки
                    int rowFinishHead = rowStartHead + 3;

                    for (int i = rowStartHead; i <= rowFinishHead; i++) {
                        XSSFRow rowHead = sheet.createRow(i);
                        Cell head0 = rowHead.createCell(0);
                        head0.setCellValue("№п/п");
                        head0.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head1 = rowHead.createCell(1);
                        head1.setCellValue("Станция отправления");
                        head1.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head2 = rowHead.createCell(2);
                        head2.setCellValue("Дорога отпр.");
                        head2.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));
                        sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 2194);

                        Cell head3 = rowHead.createCell(3);
                        head3.setCellValue("Станция назначения");
                        head3.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head4 = rowHead.createCell(4);
                        head4.setCellValue("Дорога назн.");
                        head4.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));
                        sheet.setColumnWidth(4, 2194);

                        Cell head5 = rowHead.createCell(5);
                        head5.setCellValue("Наименование груза");
                        head5.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head6 = rowHead.createCell(6);
                        head6.setCellValue("Расст., км");
                        head6.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head7 = rowHead.createCell(7);
                        head7.setCellValue("Время в пути, сут");
                        head7.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head8 = rowHead.createCell(8);
                        head8.setCellValue("Погр. / выгр.");
                        head8.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head9 = rowHead.createCell(9);
                        head9.setCellValue("Оборот, сут.");
                        head9.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head10 = rowHead.createCell(10);
                        head10.setCellValue("ВО");
                        head10.setCellStyle(cellStyleHead(sheet));

                        Cell head11 = rowHead.createCell(11);
                        if (i == rowFinishHead) {
                            head11.setCellValue("руб/ваг.");
                        } else {
                            head11.setCellValue("ДОХОД");
                        }
                        head11.setCellStyle(cellStyleHeadBottom(sheet));

                        Cell head12 = rowHead.createCell(12);
                        if (i == rowFinishHead - 1 || i == rowFinishHead - 2) {
                            head12.setCellValue("Тариф в собств. вагонах");
                        } else if (i == rowFinishHead) {
                            head12.setCellValue("руб/ваг.");
                        } else {
                            head12.setCellValue("РАСХОД");
                        }
                        head12.setCellStyle(cellStyleHeadBottom(sheet));

                        Cell head13 = rowHead.createCell(13);
                        if (i == rowFinishHead - 1 || i == rowFinishHead - 2) {
                            head13.setCellValue("За нахождение в пути");
                        } else if (i == rowFinishHead) {
                            head13.setCellValue("руб/ваг.");
                        } else {
                            head13.setCellValue("ПРИБЫЛЬ");
                        }
                        head13.setCellStyle(cellStyleHeadBottom(sheet));

                        Cell head14 = rowHead.createCell(14);
                        if (i == rowFinishHead - 1 || i == rowFinishHead - 2) {
                            head14.setCellValue("В сутки");
                        } else if (i == rowFinishHead) {
                            head14.setCellValue("руб/ваг/сут.");
                        } else {
                            head14.setCellValue("ПРИБЫЛЬ");
                        }
                        head14.setCellStyle(cellStyleHeadRight(sheet));
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowStartHead, rowFinishHead, i, i));
                    }
                    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowStartHead, rowFinishHead - 1, 11, 11));
                    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowStartHead, rowStartHead, 13, 14));
                    for (int i = 12; i < 15; i++) {
                        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowStartHead + 1, rowFinishHead - 1, i, i));
                    }

                    // Строка первого рейса
                    int rowFirstRoute = rowFinishHead + 1;
                    // Номер первой ячейки данных
                    int firstNumberCell = rowFirstRoute + 1;
                    boolean isMarker = false;

                    for (Route route : totalModel.getTotalList()) {

                        int num = rowFirstRoute + 1;
                        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowFirstRoute);
                        Cell number = row.createCell(0);
                        if (!isMarker) {
                            number.setCellValue(numberTable);
                            isMarker = true;
                        } else {
                            number.setCellValue("");
                        }
                        number.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));

                        Cell stationDeparture = row.createCell(1);
                        stationDeparture.setCellValue(route.getStationDeparture().getNameStation());
                        if (route.isFlagNeedCalc()) {
                            stationDeparture.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNeedCalc(sheet,false));
                        } else {
                            stationDeparture.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));
                        }

                        Cell roadDeparture = row.createCell(2);
                        roadDeparture.setCellValue(route.getStationDeparture().getRoad().getNameRoad());
                        if (route.isFlagNeedCalc()) {
                            roadDeparture.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNeedCalc(sheet,false));
                        } else {
                            roadDeparture.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));
                        }

                        Cell stationDestination = row.createCell(3);
                        stationDestination.setCellValue(route.getStationDestination().getNameStation());
                        if (route.isFlagNeedCalc()) {
                            stationDestination.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNeedCalc(sheet,false));
                        } else {
                            stationDestination.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));
                        }

                        Cell roadDestination = row.createCell(4);
                        roadDestination.setCellValue(route.getStationDestination().getRoad().getNameRoad());
                        if (route.isFlagNeedCalc()) {
                            roadDestination.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNeedCalc(sheet,false));
                        } else {
                            roadDestination.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));
                        }

                        Cell cargo = row.createCell(5);
                        if (route.getRate() != 0) {
                            cargo.setCellValue(route.getCargo().getNameCargo());
                            cargo.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldCargo(sheet));
                        } else {
                            cargo.setCellValue("Порожняк");
                            cargo.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldCargo(sheet));
                        }

                        Cell distance = row.createCell(6);
                        distance.setCellValue(route.getDistance());
                        distance.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldFormat(sheet, true));

                        Cell countDays = row.createCell(7);
                        countDays.setCellValue(route.getCountDays());
                        countDays.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));

                        Cell daysLoadUnload = row.createCell(8);
                        daysLoadUnload.setCellValue(route.getCountDaysLoadAndUnload());
                        daysLoadUnload.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));

                        Cell fullCountDays = row.createCell(9);
                        fullCountDays.setCellFormula("SUM(H" + num + ":I" + num + ")");
                        fullCountDays.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));

                        Cell call9 = row.createCell(10);
                        call9.setCellValue("поваг");
                        call9.setCellStyle(cellStyleField(sheet));
                        sheet.autoSizeColumn(10);

                        Cell rate = row.createCell(11);
                        if (route.getRate() == 0) {
                            rate.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNull(sheet));
                        } else {
                            rate.setCellValue(route.getRate());
                            if (route.isFlagNeedCalc()) {
                                rate.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNeedCalc(sheet, false));
                            } else {
                                rate.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldFormat(sheet, false));
                            }
                        }

                        Cell tariff = row.createCell(12);
                        if (route.getTariff() == 0) {
                            tariff.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldNull(sheet));
                        } else {
                            tariff.setCellValue(route.getTariff());
                            tariff.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldFormat(sheet, false));
                        }

                        Cell rateTariff = row.createCell(13);
                        rateTariff.setCellFormula("L" + num + "-M" + num);
                        rateTariff.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldFormat(sheet, false));
                        sheet.setColumnWidth(13, 3182);

                        Cell cell13 = row.createCell(14);
                        cell13.setCellValue("");
                        cell13.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldRightBold(sheet));

                        rowFirstRoute++;
                    }

                    // Номер последней ячейки данных
                    int lastNumberCell = rowFirstRoute;
                    int totalYieldNum = rowFirstRoute + 1;
                    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowFirstRoute);

                    Cell cell0 = row.createCell(0);
                    cell0.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
                    cell1.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
                    cell2.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell3 = row.createCell(3);
                    cell3.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell4 = row.createCell(4);
                    cell4.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell5 = row.createCell(5);
                    cell5.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowFirstRoute, rowFirstRoute, 0, 5));
                    // Строка итоговых расчетов
                    Cell totalDistance = row.createCell(6);
                    totalDistance.setCellFormula("SUM(G" + firstNumberCell + ":G" + lastNumberCell + ")");
                    totalDistance.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotalFormat(sheet, true));

                    Cell totalCountDays = row.createCell(7);
                    totalCountDays.setCellFormula("SUM(H" + firstNumberCell + ":H" + lastNumberCell + ")");
                    totalCountDays.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell totalCountLoadUnloadDays = row.createCell(8);
                    totalCountLoadUnloadDays.setCellFormula("SUM(I" + firstNumberCell + ":I" + lastNumberCell + ")");
                    totalCountLoadUnloadDays.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell totalFullCountDays = row.createCell(9);
                    totalFullCountDays.setCellFormula("SUM(J" + firstNumberCell + ":J" + lastNumberCell + ")");
                    totalFullCountDays.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell10 = row.createCell(10);
                    cell10.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell11 = row.createCell(11);
                    cell11.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell cell12 = row.createCell(12);
                    cell12.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotal(sheet));

                    Cell totalRateTariff = row.createCell(13);
                    totalRateTariff.setCellFormula("SUM(N" + firstNumberCell + ":N" + lastNumberCell + ")");
                    totalRateTariff.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotalFormat(sheet,false));

                    Cell yield = row.createCell(14);
                    yield.setCellFormula("N" + totalYieldNum + "/J" + totalYieldNum);
                    yield.setCellStyle(cellStyleFieldTotalRight(sheet, false));
                    sheet.autoSizeColumn(14);

                    Cell cell15 = row.createCell(15);
                    cell15.setCellValue(totalModel.getYield());

                    Cell cell16 = row.createCell(16);
                    cell16.setCellFormula("P" + totalYieldNum + "-O" + totalYieldNum);

                    Cell cell17 = row.createCell(17);
                    cell17.setCellFormula("Q" + totalYieldNum + "*J" + totalYieldNum);

                    rowStartHead = lastNumberCell + 1;
                    numberTable++;
                }
            }
            xssfWorkbook.write(outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }
 private static XSSFFont getFont(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFFont font = sheet.getWorkbook().createFont();
    font.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.BLACK.getIndex());
    font.setFontName("Times New Roman");
    font.setFontHeight(12.0);
    return font;
}

private static short format(XSSFSheet sheet, boolean with00) {
    XSSFDataFormat dataFormat = sheet.getWorkbook().createDataFormat();
    return with00 ? dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0") : dataFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00");
}

private static XSSFCellStyle cellStyleHead(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFont(getFont(sheet));
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new Color(255, 255, 153)));
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
    return cellStyle;
}

private static XSSFCellStyle cellStyleHeadBottom(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFont(getFont(sheet));
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new Color(255, 255, 153)));
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
    return cellStyle;
}

private static XSSFCellStyle cellStyleHeadRight(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFont(getFont(sheet));
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new Color(255, 255, 153)));
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
    return cellStyle;
}

private static XSSFCellStyle cellStyleField(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFont(getFont(sheet));
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    return cellStyle;
}

private static XSSFCellStyle cellStyleFieldFormat(XSSFSheet sheet, boolean with00) {
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFont(getFont(sheet));
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(format(sheet, with00));
    return cellStyle;
}

private static XSSFCellStyle cellStyleFieldNull(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    XSSFFont font = getFont(sheet);
    font.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.WHITE.getIndex());
    cellStyle.setFont(font);
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
    return cellStyle;
}

private static XSSFCellStyle cellStyleFieldRightBold(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFont(getFont(sheet));
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
    return cellStyle;
}

private static XSSFCellStyle cellStyleFieldCargo(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFont(getFont(sheet));
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    return cellStyle;
}

private static XSSFCellStyle cellStyleFieldNeedCalc(XSSFSheet sheet, boolean with00) {
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    XSSFFont font = getFont(sheet);
    font.setBold(true);
    cellStyle.setFont(font);
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new Color(214, 214, 214)));
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(format(sheet, with00));
    return cellStyle;
}

private static XSSFCellStyle cellStyleFieldTotal(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFont(getFont(sheet));
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
    cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new Color(204, 255, 204)));
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
    return cellStyle;
}

private static XSSFCellStyle cellStyleFieldTotalFormat(XSSFSheet sheet, boolean with00) {
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFont(getFont(sheet));
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
    cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new Color(204, 255, 204)));
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(format(sheet, with00));
    return cellStyle;
}

private static XSSFCellStyle cellStyleFieldTotalRight(XSSFSheet sheet, boolean with00) {
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFont(getFont(sheet));
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
    cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new Color(204, 255, 204)));
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(format(sheet, with00));
    return cellStyle;
}
```

Comment: @AxelRichter I added all methods. They methods are color style and border style. I need they

Comment: @AxelRichter I created classes CellStyleHead cellStyleHead = new CellStyleHead(xssfWorkbook); ... CellStyleField cellStyleField = new CellStyleField(xssfWorkbook);. And called setCellStyle(cellStyleHead.getXssfCellStyle()); But work time don't change ((

Comment: public CellStyleField(XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook) {
        this.xssfCellStyle = xssfWorkbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyleField();
    }

    private void cellStyleField() {
        // XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
        //cellStyle.setFont(getFont(sheet));
        xssfCellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.DOTTED);

Comment: I created style through the constructor in class

Comment: maybe the problem is setCellStyle() ?